# Merging data sets base on 2 columns, one name and one approximate number

Tags: r, merge, multiple-columns

I  have asked this question before and have received some help. However, I am still not able to perform what I'd like to. I think it is because I did not explain what I'd like to do well. So I'd like to try again.

Here is what I'd like to do. I have 2 data sets

Data Set A

```
   Name  Number   ValueA
 1:    A    125    16   
 2:    B    1735   76   
 3:    C    2985   22   
 4:    D    3245   76   
 5:    E    4211   22
```

Data Set B

```
   Name  Number   ValueB
 1:    A    127    56   
 2:    B    1789   84   
 3:    C    2990   11   
 4:    D    3247   36   
 5:    F    4293   49
```

I would like to merge these 2 data set base on Name and Number columns but the Number only needs to be approximately within a user defined range.

For example: I'd like to merge if the Number is +- 10 (just an example) of each other. In data set A, the name is A and Number is 125 In data set B, the name is A and Number is 127 (which is +-10 of 125)

For entry 2 is different Name is B on both, but the numbers are not +-10 of each other

Merged table:

```
   Name Number ValueA ValueB
1:   A    125     16     56
2:   B   1735     76     NA
3:   B   1789     NA    150
4:   C   2985     22     11
5:   D   3245     76     36
6:   E   4211     22     NA
7:   F   4293     NA     49
```

All help are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I tried something like this:

merge(A,B,by=c(if(abs(A$Number-B$Number)<10){"Name"}else{"Rt1"}),all=TRUE)

of course, it didn't work...just wondering if certain modification is done to the above commend, would it work?

Comment: It doesn't look as though your Number in set A actually matches your Number in Set B for Names A, C, or D. . .

Answer (score 0):

This is not beautiful, but it achieves what I think you are after. It assumes your data is in dataframes `A` and `B`.

```
M <- merge(A, B, by="Name")
M$test <- abs(M$Number.x - M$Number.y) < 10 # Hard-coded difference
M.y <- M[!M$test,]
M.y$ValueA <- NA
M.y$Number.x <- M.y$Number.y
M$ValueB[!M$test] <- NA
M <- rbind(M, M.y)
M$test <- NULL
M$Number.y <- NULL
rm(M.y)
names(M)[names(M)=="Number.x"] <- "Number"
M <- M[order(M$Number), ]
```